# Linux. Информация об открытых приложениях

Tags: linux, ssh

К примеру, я подключен через локальную сеть к одному ПК с **Linux**. Пользователь запускает какое-либо приложение. Но как записать его действие (имя открытого приложения и время) в файл?

Comment: Хотел бы уточнить: вы хотите со своего ПК отслеживать и логировать запуск процессов на другом ПК?

Comment: @NickVolynkin Да. К примеру, при запуске программы, информация сразу же (или с задержкой) отсылается на ПК администратора или в локальный файл контролируемого ПК.

Comment: тогда еще один уточняющий вопрос: нужно отслеживать все приложения или конкретные (можно перечислить списком)?

Comment: @NickVolynkin Желательно все.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

В `unix` есть очень интересная утилита - [`ps`](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ps), который выводит отчет о работающих процессах. Через параметр `o` можно указать, какую именно информацию о процессе необходимо вывести. В моем случае это:

- Команда запуска процесса;
- Пользователь, который запустил процесс;
- Время старта процесса.

А символы `>>` помогают перенаправить стандартный вывод программы `ps` в файл.

```
ps o command,user,stime >> test.log
```